# not equal operation in joining of two tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I want to join two tables ,while joining two tables in that column ,sample query is

```
    from a in project_modules
   join b in module_functions on  a.project_module_id equals b.project_module_id
```

I want not equals operation inplace of equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking literally what you ask would be:

```
from a in project_modules
from b in module_functions
where a.project_module_id != b.project_module_id
```

Note that it produces a cartesian product except the inner joined records. Well, maybe you need it for something.